# Repeat the animation only a given number of times

Tags: javascript, d3.js, while-loop

I am trying to repeat an animation via D3.js but only x times. Let's say 10 times. I used a while loop but it is a big failure.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->    
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script>

var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 960)
        .attr("height", 500);

function circleTransition() { 
    var timeCircle = svg.append("circle")
        .attr("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr("r", 20);
    repeat();

    var i=0

    function repeat() {
      timeCircle
        .attr('cx', 40)      // position the circle at 40 on the x axis
        .attr('cy', 250)     // position the circle at 250 on the y axis
        .transition()        // apply a transition
        .duration(2000)      // apply it over 2000 milliseconds
        .attr('cx', 920)     // move the circle to 920 on the x axis
        .transition()        // apply a transition
        .duration(2000)      // apply it over 2000 milliseconds
        .attr('cx', 40)      // return the circle to 40 on the x axis
        .on("end", function(i) {
                while(i < 10) {
                    repeat;
                    i++;
                }
            });        
    };

};

circleTransition();

</script>
</body>
```

My loop "while" does not work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

First, since you're calling the function it should be `repeat()`, not `repeat`. Also, since `i` is defined outside the function `repeat`, the callback should be just:

```
.on("end", function() {
```

... not:

```
.on("end", function(i) {
```

Because here `i` is `undefined`.

But that's not the real problem. The biggest problem here is that it's complicated pausing or delaying JavaScript loops: that `while` loop will run immediately to the end, in few milliseconds, calling `repeat` ten times at once.

Instead of that, you can just do:

```
.on("end", function() {
    if (i > 9) return;
    i++;
    repeat();
});
```

Or, to save 1 line:

```
.on("end", function() {
    if (++i > 9) return;
    repeat();
});
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 600)
  .attr("height", 100);

function circleTransition() {
  var timeCircle = svg.append("circle")
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("r", 20);
  repeat();

  var limit = 4;
  var i = 0

  document.getElementById("iterations").innerText = i + "/" + limit;

  function repeat() {
    timeCircle
      .attr('cx', 40) // position the circle at 40 on the x axis
      .attr('cy', 50) // position the circle at 250 on the y axis
      .transition() // apply a transition
      .duration(1000) // apply it over 2000 milliseconds
      .attr('cx', 520) // move the circle to 920 on the x axis
      .transition() // apply a transition
      .duration(1000) // apply it over 2000 milliseconds
      .attr('cx', 40) // return the circle to 40 on the x axis
      .on("end", function() {
        if (++i > limit) return;
        document.getElementById("iterations").innerText = i + "/" + limit;
        repeat();
      });
  };

};

circleTransition();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<p>Iteration:
  <span id="iterations" />
</p>
```